# SSH and SCP failed with "CreateProcessW failed error:2 posix_spawn: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ssh, cmd, scp

I am trying to do SSH and SCP to AWS managed instance. The public key of my machine is stored at that managed instance. There is no .pem file required. I am using the following commands.

```
   scp -r  username@instance-id:/pathtoremotefile localpath
   scp localfilepath  username@instance-id:~
   ssh  username@instance-id
```

But none of these are working in windows.The error says,"CreateProcessW failed error:2 posix_spawn: No such file or directory lost connection". I would mention that I am able to start ssm session to that instance using this command

```
   aws ssm start-session --target instance-id.
```

Managed instance has linux operating system and my pc has windows.
Also, in config file of .ssh directory, I've added following lines.

```
 host i-* mi-*
ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

The strange thing is I am able to do both ssh and SCP in 'windows subsystem from Linux' from the same machine by using the same commands. But couldn't do that in windows command prompt.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of the Windows openSSH package.
In ProxyCommands it requests full path qualifiers, but better use forward slashes there!

```
ProxyCommand C:/somepath/sh.exe -c "aws ssm ...
```

I don't use the windows openSSH anymore, instead I'm using the ssh command from git-bash to avoid all the windows problems.
The key agent works perfect, proxyCommand/proxyJumps works, and in contrast to windows, it's reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @jeb but I didn't get it. Which path am I supposed to give there?

Comment: @Jass In your example you used `sh`, so you need the full windows path to that executable.

Comment: Thanks @jeb , I understood what I was doing wrong. The proxy command that I should use was different. I was using linux command , but for windows, it should be like this:   # SSH over Session Manager
host i-* mi-*
    ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p". Thanks I got the way from your answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the answer. It works on my machine.

Comment: That's Great! @MichalŠípek

Answer (score 0):

Just for tip.

Thanks to the other previous answers and comments, I solved my issue similar to @jass.

For me, I got the same error message when I tried to connect to ec2 through *ec2 instance connect endpoint* in case of 'Single connection'.

(ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connect-using-eice.html#eic-connect-using-ssh)

I was trying in Windows 10, and using aws cli v2, and have already configured 'aws configure' with aws Access key & Secret key.

This is the command string I found.

```
ssh -i ~somin/.ssh/[xxxx.pem] ec2-user@[i-xxxxxxxxx] -o "ProxyCommand C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id [i-xxxxxxxxx]"
```

P.s
However, if you tried 'Multi-connection', you would face no error. Because process has two steps, and there is no path issue.